# Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

do anyone has an idea

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 79" at xxxxx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/RegexValidator.php line 45 {"exception"
```

the line 45 and above contains this

```
            45| if ($constraint->match xor preg_match($constraint->pattern, $value)) {
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                    ->setParameter('{{ value }}', $this->formatValue($value))
                    ->setCode(Regex::REGEX_FAILED_ERROR)
                    ->addViolation();
            }
```

I have added recently two fields in the form, please note that I am using Symfony 3.4
If you need more clarification don't hesitate to tell me.
thanks

Comment: What is the value of `$constraint->pattern`? Does it include delimiters?

Comment: the problem is from regex

Comment: Yes, that is obvious. Can you answer my question about the value of the parameter?

Comment: If you know "the problem is from regex" SHOW the regex in your question!